# How to adjust the code to download full size content?

Tags: android

How to download full size content. I followed android [Connecting to the Network](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html) tutorial and they are mentioning int len = 500; it's downloading 500 character only my [Api](https://newstimeapp.herokuapp.com/api/news) returns more than character. So how to adjust the code to download full content ?

Below is the code currently having ...

```
private String downloadUrl(String myurl) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = null;
    // Only display the first 500 characters of the retrieved
    // web page content.
    int len = 500;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(myurl);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        // Starts the query
        conn.connect();
        int response = conn.getResponseCode();
        is = conn.getInputStream();

        // Convert the InputStream into a string
        String contentAsString = readIt(is, len);
        return contentAsString;

        // Makes sure that the InputStream is closed after the app is
        // finished using it.
    } finally {
        if (is != null) {
            is.close();
        }
    }
}
// Reads an InputStream and converts it to a String.
public String readIt(InputStream stream, int len) throws IOException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    Reader reader = null;
    reader = new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8");
    char[] buffer = new char[len];
    reader.read(buffer);
    return new String(buffer);
}
```

I event tried increasing len value to 5000 and also having the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this instead of or inside `public String readIt`

```
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
       total.append(line);
}
String resultString = total.toString()
```